# not null and no empty char in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

how do for stablish a column varchar in mysql workbench as not null and not allow empty string or blank string?.

values not allowed

```
''
'   '
NULL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes more sense to do input validation on the application level rather than on the DB level.

If you really insist, you can use triggers to generate an error.
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html